# Flutter - Dynamically add widgets to a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, queue, stack

I'm trying to add widgets to the end of a Queue of children for a Stack when a button is pressed. The button is supposed to remove the first element from the Queue and add another element to the end. In doing so, the second element would take the place of the first. For example:

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestStacking extends StatefulWidget {
  Queue<Widget> stackChildren = new Queue<Widget>();

  @override
  _TestStackingState createState() => _TestStackingState();
}

class _TestStackingState extends State<TestStacking> {

  void _addChild() {
    int position = widget.stackChildren.length;
    Widget child = Card(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text(
        "This card is in position $position",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      widget.stackChildren.addLast(child);
    });
  }

  void _removeChild() {
    setState(() {
      widget.stackChildren.removeFirst();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _addChild();
    _addChild();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _addChild();
                _removeChild();
              },
              child: Text(
                "Add Child",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: widget.stackChildren.toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

In this example, I can only get the first 2 entries I put in the initState to function properly, but I want to add more entries that I didn't initialize in the initState. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The reason is that when press the button, it add one and del one, the length is always 2

Comment: Ah, you're right. Then it does work.

Comment: It should be fine so far